# "Function was not declared" during multiple file compilation in C++

Tags: c++, reusability

My source files look like the following

```
//functions.h
#ifdef FUNCTIONS
#define FUNCTIONS

bool isPrime(int num);

#endif

//function.cpp
include "functions.h"
bool isPrime(int num) {...}

//main.cpp
#include "functions.h"
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << isPrime(2);
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled them with
g++ -o main main.cpp functions.cpp

It gave me the error message "isPrime" was not declared in this scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is so simple I didn't see it at first. Instead of `#ifdef FUNCTIONS` you need `#ifndef FUNCTIONS`. Note the `n`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H
#define FUNCTIONS_H
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what compiler you use, you could also use the following directive:

```
#pragma once
```

What this does is tell the compiler, "Hey, `#include` me only once", just like with the header guards. It may, however, be more effective in preventing redefinition linker errors.